# Continuity of a function for $2 x^2 +y$

Tags: limits, continuity

Can you please explain why $f(x,y) = 2x^2 +y$ 
is discontinuous at $(x,y) = (1,2)$. I took the line $y-2=m(x-1)$. This gives the limit as 3. But the book says its discontinuous. Please Help
 Thanks

Comment: I think it's continuous.

Answer (score 1):

The function $f(x,y) = 2x^2 +y$ (a polynomial in two variables) is continuous at any point $(x_0,y_0)\in\mathbb{R}^2$.
$$\lim_{(x,y)\to (x_0,y_0)} \left(2x^2 +y\right)=2x_0^2 +y_0.$$

Comment: @YashJain The answer is correct, but what led you to thinking the function was discontinuous? Because that is a conceptual error, it would be good if we cleared that too. But it seems like you are using one of those Indian textbooks. I never took the answers from them. I remember once, the question said differentiate the following functions, and at the back all the integrals were given.

Answer (score 0):

To add to Robert Z's answer: the composition of continuous functions is continuous; the projection functions are continuous; multiplication by a constant is continuous; addition is continuous; squaring is continuous. This is probably the quickest way to see why the original function is continuous.